# How to match a list with my firebase documents list out of order?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

if I want to find a document in a collection where my list is equal to that of the document I would do so like;
`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("movies/collection/").where("my_list", isEqualTo: movie_list).limit(1).get();`

but in this way the ordering of `my_list` and `movie_list` matters and has to match exactly.. I need some way of checking that the two list have the exact same movies in them, regardless of the ordering

Comment: Hello, if my answer was useful you can accept (✔) and upvote () it. Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: Can you use `.where(..., arrayContains: movie_list)` and then filter the results to exclude lists that have a length different than `movie_list`?

Comment: @jamesdlin maybe, yes. Didn't try tho'. Ended up completely changing my database scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `array-contains-all` operator and hence you cannot check if more than one items exists in an array. Even if you have all the elements of the array they must be in same order. If you could make sure the order is always alphabetical (or any particular pattern) that may work out.

However, I'd recommend converting that to a map which will be easier to query. So instead of `["one", "two"]`, a map like `{"one": true, "two": true}` can be queried by chaining multiple `.where("myMap.one", isEqualTo: true)` clauses.

Comment: A `Set` would be a more appropriate data structure.